# How to copy an image with a mask keeping original color in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, mask

I have a color image that I want to copy to a white image, but only certain pixels. I want to keep the original colors of those pixels in the white image. I'm using a mask and copyTo function, but the resulting image is shown in only one color. What am I doing wrong? The input is a photo of a lined paper sheet with a hand-drawn figure and what I'm trying to do is only retain the figure and the lines with their colors in a white image (to get rid of the noise, shadows and wrinkles).

```
 Mat src = imread("D:/Images/test.jpg", 1);  
imshow("input", src);
```

[image: input]

```
Mat gray;
Mat dst_eq = adaptiveHistogramEqualization(src); //adaptive histogram equalization to enhance contrast
imshow("adaptive histogram", dst_eq);
cvtColor(dst_eq, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(5, 5), 0, 0);
adaptiveThreshold(~gray, binary, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 3, -2); //binary mask 
imshow("binary mask", ~binary);
```

[image: binary mask]

```
Mat white2 = Mat(src.size(), src.type()); 
white2 = cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255);
src.copyTo(white2, ~binary);
imshow("Result", white2);
```

[image: Result]

If this can be done differently, please tell me. BTW, Does anyone know how to get rid of the lines in the paper? Taking into account that the photos will be taken with a phone, therefore it will be important lighting variations, and the sheet could have square or lined background, and the lines could be of different colors (not necessarily blue). I tried color segmentation (supposing blue lines) with no success due to the lighting variations and noise. I also tried morphological transformations. In both cases, it is impossible to remove the background and keep the figure intact in all my test images.

[image: Input, before copy]

Comment: can you add imshow("input before copy", src); right before src.copyTo line? This would show whether your src Mat was altered by any operation.

Comment: btw, is your imshow("binary mask", ~binary); result what you expected it to be? So is your mask ok?

Comment: @Micka Thanks for replying. I just posted the photo of the input before copy. As it can be seen, it hasn't been modified by any operation. The mask is ok, I mean, I want all the non-zero pixels (white) pixels in mask, but with their original color. Indeed my goal is to filter only the hand-drawn figure, but I haven't been able to achieve it, so I thought it could be easier if I first do what I'm asking for.

Comment: can you post your result image, too? It should be a white image with blue horizontal lines and black drawing, right? And your question is about that this isnt the case?

Comment: The result image is the third image I've posted. Right, this image isn't as I expected to be. It has gray horizontal lines and gray drawing.

Comment: sorry, thought this was inserve of the mask... can you try to create a mask manually (e.g. draw a filled circle in the image) and use coopyTo with that mask?